# Calling third party javascript function in angular typescript onInit()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some javascript function named xyz, and in my head element I call the script:

`<script async src="https://someurl.com/thescript.js"></script>`

I have received instructions that function xyz located in thescript.js will reload something on my component everytime I open it.

I have tried to call this function directly from component html, but I believe that I need to call it in the onInit function in typescript, but I do not know how to make reference to the third party js file and call its function.